# how does expo-router implement react-safe-area-context in the background?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I installed *expo-router* 2.0 into my new project with expo sdk 49 as specified in the documentation
https://docs.expo.dev/routing/installation/#install-dependencies

```bash
npx expo install expo-router react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens expo-linking expo-constants expo-status-bar react-native-gesture-handler
```

there is one thing  I realized when created first view in my app, it is uncovered in the doc;

the content was already padded below status bar. so i don't need to use *SafeAreaView* as

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

because the content i add in the /app directory already has that padding. so, i only do

```
import { View } from 'react-native';

function SomeComponent() {
  return (
      <View />
  );
}
```

and it works as i want.

should I trust this behaviour of expo-router? would it cause problems in the future?

Comment: Hello, I've previously explored this, and indeed, the brief answer is affirmative. However, for a more comprehensive explanation, it pertains to the encapsulation of your component within the Expo Router. To assist you more effectively, could you please clarify the specific concerns or issues you have in mind?

check expo-router files like ExpoRoot.tsx ,...